# Unit testing framework for xsl-fo

Tags: unit-testing, xsl-fo

I need to run unit tests on xsl-fo. I wanted to know if there are any frameworks I can use.
utf-x seems to be very complicated

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to test? UTF-X ([project](http://utf-x.sourceforge.net/history.html) looks abandoned, btw) is a testing framework for XSLT, not XSL-FO.

Comment: Would an XML-diffing library do the trick for you? What programming language do you want to trigger your tests from? (I could find something in Java)

Comment: I am working on a framework that does this since I could not find any. It takes in an XML, XSL, and a test file which describes what data is expected (must be present vs must not be present). If there is any interest in this question please revive this post / add comment / or add a discussion here.

Comment: http://utf-x.sourceforge.net/index.html UTF-X allows xsl:fo unit testing

Answer (score 1):

Antenna House Regression Testing System (http://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/antenna-house-regression-testing-system/) can run your FO and give you a pixel-by-pixel comparison between the formatted output and a reference output.

If you want to test the XSLT that produces the FO, look at XSpec (https://github.com/expath/xspec).